# bcp export varbinary to flat file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to export varbinary with bcp to a flat file (csv).
It seems to work, but in front of the 0x is a strange enconding, I can not get rid of. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Following the bcp-command I execute and the screenshot from notepad++

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CONVERT(varchar(max), [Bild],1) AS SomeImageFieldAsHex FROM [SWTA_HH].[dbo].[Fenster]" queryout "c:\export.csv" -d "SWTA_HH" -T -n -r \n
```

[image: varbinary encoding]

Thanks Darius

Comment: `-n` is telling BCP to output "native" format data, so the things ahead of the 0x are attributes important to SQL Server.

Comment: Are these characters actually a problem? have you tried importing into the other side?

Comment: I want to import the csv into APEX, though I do not need that native formatiing - without -n bcp asks me to fill in the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) documentation, the [-n switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#n) is instructing BCP to output data in "native" format, which includes binary information to allow a receiving SQL Server to ingest the data again using the correct data types.

If you're wanting to output these varbinary values to a .CSV (comma-separated values) file then you'll probably want to use the [-c switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#c) instead, for character data, e.g.:

```
bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CONVERT(varchar(max), [Bild], 1) AS SomeImageFieldAsHex FROM [SWTA_HH].[dbo].[Fenster]" queryout "c:\export.csv" -d "SWTA_HH" -T -c -r \n
```