# Azure Data Factory: Lookup varbinary column in SQL DB for use in a Script activity to write to another SQL DB - ByteArray is not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to insert into an on-premises SQL database table called PictureBinary:

[PictureBinary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x99lr.png)

The source of the binary data is a table in another on-premises SQL database called DocumentBinary:

[DocumentBinary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwxBk.png)

I have a file with all of the Id's of the DocumentBinary rows that need copying. I feed those into a ForEach activity from a Lookup activity. Each of these files has about 180 rows (there are 50 files fed into a new instance of the pipeline in parallel).

[Lookup and ForEach Activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBgsJ.png)

So far everything is working. But then, inside the ForEach I have another Lookup activity that tries to get the binary info to pass into a script that will insert it into the other database.

[Lookup Binary column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou2NA.png)

And then the Script activity would insert the binary data into the table PictureBinary (in the other database).

[Script to Insert Binary data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXsP9.png)

But when I debug the pipeline, I get this error when the binary column Lookup is reached:

> ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column: coBinaryData,The data type ByteArray is not supported from the column named coBinaryData.,Source=,'

I know that the accepted way of storing the files would be to store them on the filesystem and just store the file path to the files in the database. But we are using a NOP database that stores the files in varbinary columns.

Also, if there is a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried transferring this via `BCP`? It's a far simpler option. make sure you use the -n option. This quetion shows the approach but since they are not importing into SQL Server that are having issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466939/bcp-export-varbinary-to-flat-file

Comment: I just realised this is cloud so you may not want to use `BCP`. I would approach this by using a standard data copy to copy into a staging table in the target then use a script or stored procedure to process staging into the final table required. This is an "ELT" approach which is frequently simpler, fast, and cheaper than the "ETL" approach which you have used

Comment: can you please share sample file content??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is not recommended to use pictures in questions. You can utilize table feature as described https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and got similar error

[image]

As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) Columns with datatype Byte Array Are not supported in lookup activity is might be the main cause of error.

[image]

**To workaround this as Follow below steps:**

As you explained your case you have a file in which all the Id's of the DocumentBinary rows that need copy in destination are stored. To achieve this, **you can simply use Copy activity with the Query** where you copy records where the **`DocumentBinary`  in column is equal to the `Id` stored in file**

First, I took lookup activity from where I can get Id's of the DocumentBinary rows stored in file

[image]

Then I took ForEach I passed the output of lookup activity to ForEach activity.

[image]

After this I took Copy activity in forEach activity

```sql
Select * from DocumentBinary
where coDocumentBinaryId = '@{item().PictureId}'
```

In source of copy activity **select Use query as** `Query` and pass above query with your names

[image]

Now **go to Mapping Click** on `Import Schema` then delete unwanted columns and map the columns accordingly.

> **Note**: For this, columns in both tables are of similar datatypes either both `uniqueidenntifier` or both should be `int`

[image]

Sample Input in file:

[image]

**Output (Copied only picture id contend in file from source to destination):**

[image]